# Scrolling behavior confusing me

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have some overflow hidden div. inside of it there are li elements and I try to scroll the div to the scrolltop of 6 elements further (with buttons).

http://jsbin.com/ejobuw/6

But the scrollbehavior is confusing me.
onclick it scroll to the middle of the element on the next click to the real position and it dont scrolling to the end.
could somebody help me please.

ps sorry for my school english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using `offset()` which retrieves the current position of an element *relative to the page* - but since you move those elements around, the offset changes.

Try this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var offset = $("a").eq(6).offset().top;

    var scrollList = function() {
        $('#thumb_keeper').animate({
            scrollTop: offset * i
        }, 500);
    };

    $('.scroll_down').click(function () {
        i++;
        scrollList();
    });

    $('.scroll_up').click(function () {
        i--;
        scrollList();
    });    
});
```

You will need to make some other changes to check if you can scroll further down, otherwise `i` must not be incremented. Same goes for scrolling up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes i will test the schrollposition. but the srollposition isnt already the top of the li see [link](http://jsbin.com/ejobuw/8).

Comment: Okay, 1) start with `i=0` 2) you will need to reduce the `offset` var by the vertical offset of the container (#thumb_keeper) e.g. `var offset = $('a:eq(6)').offset().top - $('#thumb_keeper').offset().top;` 3) even then this will only work nicly, if all paddings/margins between the <li>s are the same.